# Polling an external data source within a Flink Operator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an unkeyed `FilterFunction` that keeps a set of items it should filter. I need this set to be updated regularly from an external HTTP API. As items come in, we check to see if they're on the list and filter them out if not.

A few specific questions:

- Are there any best practices for setting up a poller, such as with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, within the `FilterFunction`?
- How can I ensure there is just one poller at any time, hopefully without setting the filter's parallelism to 1?
- Should I store the returned items in a managed `ListState` or raw state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proposal that should help with some of the issues you've asked about:

Create a custom source that does the polling, with parallelism of 1. It can broadcast what it finds to a fleet of BroadcastProcessFunctions that do the filtering. Keep the set of allowed items in MapState, which will make the filter lookups efficient.